# How to add custom html bootstrap select picker?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap select picker for dropdown, it form a drop down with ul, li.

But i would like to prepend some custom html to show small images for each option.

https://embed.plnkr.co/SQt0hSykjjWEym0Rj8X4/

In the above example we could see list of options such as chicken, turkey etc. i need to add a span which will hold a small image for each option,

```
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option"aria-disabled="false">
<span class="{{img}}"></span>
<span class="text">chicken</span>
</a>
```

How to do that.

am using Bootstrap-select v1.13.2 
    (https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select)

Comment: If you want to insert additional HTML elements into the structure BS-select creates, you will probably need to write your own JS code to do that after the plugin has initialized on a field (and maybe take care of _updates_ as well.) This would be much easier, if you used a CSS pseudo child (`::before`)  instead, then you could do it using CSS alone. (Specifics depending on how you want to target specific option elements - based on order, value attribute content, …)

Comment: Here i cant use pseudo because i have a sprite image and class which has different background-position for all options. i am unable to find any documentation to prepend some custom html,

Comment: _“and class which has different background-position for all options”_ - so rewrite the selectors to target the appropriate pseudo elements then …?

Comment: those are 100+ reused class, .img-ck{ background-position: -24px 0}; .img-tk{ background-position: -48px 0}; in such cases its not possible to change all the 100+ classes. any other idea to convert class pointing to pseudo ?

Comment: So how would you want to associate a given option with a specific class then to begin with?

Comment: i dont have any idea, i would like to go with prepend html once dropdown rendered

Comment: I got data-content which do my job. what do say?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but it may help someone searching for a solution.
If you want to add custom content you have to use the data attribute "content".

For example here i create a span with a glyphicon (Bootstrap 3, but you can use FontAwesome or another icon), and a span element with custom content:

```
<option data-content="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plane'></span>&nbsp;<span class='customClass' data-custom='customvalue'>customText</span>">
</option>
```

If you want to use custom attribute for your element inside data-content, you have to register it inside your javascript (bedofe the selectpicker command) like:

```
var myDefaultWhiteList = $.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.DEFAULTS.whiteList;
//To allow data-custom for span elements
myDefaultWhiteList.span = ['data-custom'];
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if that what you want, but try to give back-ground to the option as

```
<option style="background-image:url('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/bright-spring-view-cameo-island-260nw-1048185397.jpg');background-size:20px 20px;background-repeat: no-repeat ">
chicken
</option>
```